# Swift how to get response.statuscode in swiftui view

Tags: swift, postgresql, swiftui

I am trying insert into db use post method in swift
and i can not get the response.statusCode of post method in swiftui view
how can i fix it.
the variable self.resp should be 201 in view when I insert successfully, but 
it was 0.

```js
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
  @State var resp:Int  = 0
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
        Text("Hello, World!")
        Button(action: {
            self.resp = postAdd()
            print("view\(self.resp)")
        }) {
            Text(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/"Button"/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
              
                
                .background(self.resp == 201 ? Color.green : Color.gray)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
func postAdd() ->Int{
            let url = URL(string: "http://localhost:3000/user")
            var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
    var resp = 0
                       request.httpMethod = "POST"
                        let urlstr = "id=5&name=aaa"
    
            request.httpBody = urlstr.data(using: .utf8)!
            let session = URLSession.shared
            session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
                if error == nil, let data = data, let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
                                   print("Content-Type: \(response.allHeaderFields["Content-Type"] ?? "")")
                                      print("statusCode: \(response.statusCode)")
                    resp = response.statusCode
                    print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) ?? "")
                }
            }.resume()
    return resp
        }
```

Comment: You have to work with completion pattern, because the urlrequest is asynchron. Or you insert your func in your view and instead of returning the value you set your state variable where you now set your resp var.

Comment: can you show me a code sample,I can not undstand what you said

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

as i wrote in the comment - you have to know which calls are async and which are sync. I hope you know what sync and async calls are - if not, please google for it. if yes: the data task call is async and so it returns directly the resp = 0 value. After some time when the urlrequest is ready, it continuous in this line : "{ (data, response, error) in", but here it cannot return a value anymore because the method already returned a value. So with the completion pattern you can be sure you will get called when the async call is ready.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var resp:Int  = 0
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("Hello, World!")
            Button(action: {
                postAdd() { response in
                    self.resp = response

                    print("view\(self.resp)")
                }
            }) {
                Text(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/"Button"/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                    .background(self.resp == 201 ? Color.green : Color.gray)
            }
        }
    }
}


func postAdd(completion:@escaping(Int)->()) {
    let url = URL(string: "http://localhost:3000/user")
    var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let urlstr = "id=5&name=aaa"

    request.httpBody = urlstr.data(using: .utf8)!
    let session = URLSession.shared
    session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        if error == nil, let data = data, let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
            print("Content-Type: \(response.allHeaderFields["Content-Type"] ?? "")")
            print("statusCode: \(response.statusCode)")
            completion(response.statusCode)
            print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) ?? "")
        } else {
            completion(404)
        }
    }.resume()

}
```